# how to formally prove that $R[x]/ \langle f(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $R[α]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $R$ be a ring, let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $f(x)\in R[x]$. How can I formally prove that the kernel of the evaluation map $\phi:R[x]\rightarrow R[\alpha]$ defined as $f(x)\mapsto f(\alpha)$ is $\langle f(x)\rangle$?

EDIT: the original statement is incorrect. But now how to formally prove that $R[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $R[α]$?

**EDIT**: In Artin algebra page 339, we denote the ring we get by adjointing a toot of $f$ by $R$, if the 2 rings are not isomorphic, why are we able to do that? Could someone please explain? Thanks in advance！
[image]

Comment: You cannot, because it is not true. Notably because if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $\alpha$ is also a root of $gf$ for any $g$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If it is not true then we cannot conclude that $R[x]/<f(x)>$ is isomorphic to $R[\alpha]$ using the first isomorphism theorem. So see the edited question, may I please ask how to formally prove that $R[x]/<f(x)>$ is isomorphic to $R[\alpha]$?

Comment: What kind of ring is $R$?  Commutative, a domain, a field, what?

Comment: The statement is true when $R$ is a field and $f$ is irreducible. This depends on the fact that if $R$ is a field, then $R[x]$ is a PID.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Thanks a lot! But in the picture in Artin algebra above,  why are we able to denote the quotient ring as $R[\alpha]$ if they are not isomorpic? And could you please give an example if there is some case that the 2 rings are not isomorphic?

Comment: @BobJones R is any commutitive ring.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise With a little bit more effort, we can generalize this to the case where $R$ is a normal domain and $\alpha$ is integral over this domain. The PID property of $R[x]$ is nice to have for an easy proof, but it is not essential.

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot of that proposition is just a definition. For an abstract ring $R$, the notion $R[\alpha]$ does make any sense a priori. This is why he defines the notion $R[\alpha]$ as $R[\alpha] := R[x]/(f)$. $\alpha$ is just a symbol, namely a symbol for the residue class of $x$ in $R[x]/(f)$. The definition is however motivated from the following fact:

> Let $R$ be a normal domain and $\alpha$ an element of the algebraic closure of
>   the fraction field $K$ of $R$, which is integral over $R$. Then
>   $R[\alpha] \cong R[x]/(f)$, where $f$ is the unique monic minimal
>   polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, which happens to have coefficients in
>   $R$.

Note that in this case, the notion $R[\alpha]$ makes sense a priori, because it ist just defined as the intersection of all subrings of $\overline K$, that contain $R$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that comes across here is that when we're modding out by the ideal generated by $f(x)$, the class $\overline{x}$ of $x$ in the quotient ring satisfies $f(\overline{x})=0$ because $f(\overline{x})=\overline{f(x)}=\overline{0}$.  So if you define $\alpha=\overline{x}$, then $R[\alpha]$ is exactly isomorphic to $R[x]/(f(x))$, because the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ is exactly $f$ by definition.  So you may use the first isomorphism theorem with the map $x\rightarrow\alpha$, and the kernel will be exactly multiples of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. Where I am stucking at is the procedure of proving $ker=<f(x)>$, the trivial direction is $<f(x)>\subset I$ since all the multiples of $f(x)$ are mapped to zero? But how can I see that $I\subset <f(x)>$? I tried the division algorithm but I cannot prove it yet.

Comment: Well, what could be in the kernel?  It has to be of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$ for $a_i\in R$, right?  These are the only things in the ring $R[x]$.  But when we map this to $R[\alpha]$, we get $a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+\ldots+a_n\alpha^n$.  But remember that $\alpha=\overline{x}$, the class of $x\mod f(x)$, so this is just the class of $a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ mod $f(x)$.  When is this $0$?  Exactly when $a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ is a multiple of $f(x)$, by definition.  So the kernel is contained in $(f(x))$, so it's exactly equal to it.